# fit ML model multiple times on same dataset to get average accuracy score in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am on windows10 using sklearn==0.24.1

I know when we want to average accuracy of our model we usually do k-fold cross validation and average accuracy score for each fold. However in such case we are using different parts of training sets to train.

I am trying to calculate average accuracy score of my model using same train dataset.

```
acc_scores = []
for i in range(10):
    random_clf = RandomForestClassifier()
    random_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = random_clf.predict(X_test)
    acc_scores.append(round(accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test), 2))
np.mean(acc_scores)
```

This is my current approach, which to me looks fine however am curious to know if there might be something I am misunderstanding or other simpler tricks to achieve this.

EDIT: Unlike question that marks my question as duplicate

1. In my case I am using **same** X_train, y_train for each iteration
2. Creating RandomForestClassifer() at each iteration thus acc_scores list has all different scores. So I am thinking there is no need to clone my RFC model.

Comment: Sorry I missed your edit (in the future, pls notify whoever might have closed it with a @ in a comment). Regarding (2), this was the case in the dup, too - don't know why someone (not the OP) changed this (I edited back). Regarding (1), it does not actually make any difference. In any case, if you find you do not need `clone()`, the procedure as you post it here is just fine.